# How do you console log inside a knockout template

Tags: knockout.js

I thought this was correct:

```
            <div data-bind="foreach: amount_options, visible: $parent.displayAskAmoutRadioButtons()">
                <!-- ko console.log(amount_option) --><!-- /ko -->
                <label class="donor-js-amount-choice">
                    <!-- <input type="radio" class="donor-js-webware" name="gift_amt" data-bind="attr: {value: key}, checked: $parent.amountSelected"><span class="donor-js-currency-symbol" data-bind="html: $root.session.currencySymbol"></span>&nbsp;<span class="donor-js-input-currency" data-bind="text: desc"></span>&nbsp;<span class="donor-js-input-currency"></span><br> -->
                </label>
            </div>
```

apparently not as nothing gets out put to the console. The commented out line of tag is throwing an error about the `value: key` and I need to know whats inside of one of these `amount_options`.

**Ideas?**

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try this. Knockout should evaluate value for binding and flush to console.

```
<div data-bind="text: console.log(amount_option)"></div>
```

Comment: I know this was written in 2016 but i don't think this answer is correct since console.log() returns undefined text KO should then throw an error.

Comment: This worked for me with Knockout 3.4 and Rails 5.2 :    `<input data-bind="text: console.log('knockout exec at <%= __FILE__ +':'+ __LINE__.to_s %>') " />`

Comment: Thanks @JulienLamarche for non rails setups <input data-bind="text: console.log(element)" /> seems to work.