# Log a foreach element knockout.js

Tags: php, knockout.js

I'm trying to log a knockout.js value (really new with this tech).
I found this issue I tried to follow: [How do you console log inside a knockout template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109051/how-do-you-console-log-inside-a-knockout-template)

But it's not working (there is already working code inside that loop but I want to log it.

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: tableData().offer_formulas, as: '$formulaRow' } -->
    <div data-bind="text: console.log($formulaRow)"></div>
```

But this is triggering the following error in console :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return tableData().product_groups.length > 0 }"
>   Message: Unable to process binding "text: function(){return console.log($formulaRow) }"

That's my current issue, but in fact what I'm trying to do is getting one of the specific values.

At the moment here is what is binded (done by an other dev)

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: tableData().offer_formulas, as: '$formulaRow' } -->
    <th class="data-grid-th" data-bind="attr:{colspan: $parent.getDurationsCountForFormula($formulaRow.id)}">
        <input class="admin__control-text" type="text" data-bind="value:$parent.getString($parent.formulas(), $index(), 'label')" />
```

The value I want I know how to get it on php size, the structure is as follow

```
$data = $bc_offer_configuration->data;
if($bc_offer_configuration != null && $data != null){
    $offer_formulas = $data->offer_formulas;
    foreach ($offer_formulas as $offer_formula){
        $LabelIWantToGetInKnockoutJs = $offer_formula->label;
```

I can see the structure seems to be similar but I don't know how to access the element I need.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Kurano, the logging in your snippet is not the one which causes the error. The error referes to an `if` binding, which is not provided in your question.

Comment: @HeyJude I don't think so cause if I remove the line with console.log I do not have any error any more on this.

Comment: @Kurano, read your error carefully. Note that it refers to something that's not present in your snippet: `if: tableData().product_groups.length > 0`. Can you add this code to your question?

Comment: @Kurano can i see your whole VM.

When your VM is initialized you should be able to see the text in your browsers debugger.

Another great solution is from your browser select the element that you would like to see the data for and just use ko.dataFor($0) method that is already provided and it will give you a snap shot of what your VM data is.

Comment: afaik you can just enter the console and type `vm.tableData()` or whatever var you bound your vm to